# CloudKit Record creation push notification

Tags: push-notification, cloudkit

I am receiving a notification from CloudKit when a record with 'message' field is created. I would like to show to the user on the lock screen the content of the message. could you help me with that.

Comment: I found the solution, you should just update the notificationInfo properly,notificationInfo.desiredKeys = ["message"]
        notificationInfo.alertBody = nil
        notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "%@"
        notificationInfo.alertLocalizationArgs = ["message"]
        notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true

Answer (score 0):

You have to deliver a **Local Notification** to the user. You should read the Apple's [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1) about this topic.

You could send this notification inside the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function in `AppDelegate` class

The way to process the userInfo dictionary received as a parameter must be processed with `CKNotification` class [initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cknotification/1428130-init).

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. You could just use the `notificationInfo` property @Arash mentions in his comment above.